# What is a parallel line?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

We are learning vectors in class and I have a question about parallel lines and coincident lines. According to wikipedia a parallel line is:

> Two lines in a plane that do not intersect or touch at a point are called parallel lines.

But another reference says

> Side by side and having the same distance continuously between them.

According to the above definition, you can have two parallel lines with a distance of zero but this contradicts the first definition. So which is it?

EDIT:

If it is the second definition then you can have two lines that are coincident and parallel right?

Comment: I think one can combine both definitions

Comment: I think it is an interesting question what "constant distance" between two lines actually means - it requires some definition of distance, which may not be a primitive concept, while incidence tends to be primitive (properties defined in axioms).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's always important, in situations like this, to recall the immortal words of [Humpty Dumpty](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Humpty_Dumpty) (via Lewis Carroll's *[Through the Looking Glass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Through_the_Looking-Glass)*):

> "When *I* use a word, [...] it means just what I choose it to mean --- neither more nor less."

Indeed, Wikipedia's discussion of "[Equivalent Properties](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_postulate#Equivalent_properties)" to [Euclid's Parallel Postulate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_postulate) notes **four** "common definitions" of the term *parallel*: (1) constant separation, (2) never meeting, (3) same angles where crossed by some third line, or (4) same angles where crossed by any third line. (I'd say that (3) and (4) are slightly-nuanced ways of conveying the common notion of parallel lines "pointing in the same direction".)

Observe how these *four* "common definitions" apply to your "distance of zero" (aka, "coincident") lines:

1. Constant separation *holds* ... provided you allow that "separation by distance zero" counts as "separation". (That, too, is a choice.)
2. Never meeting *fails*: coincident lines meet *everywhere*.
3. Same angles where crossed by some third line *holds*: coincident lines are going to make identical angles!
4. Same angles where crossed by any third line *holds*: as in 3.

That's either 3-to-1 in favor of "coincident lines are parallel", or a 2-2 split decision; so the answer to your question "So, which is it?" is: **It depends.**

---

Personally, I'm a big fan of the "never meeting" definition of parallelism; it just seems the cleanest formulation. Number of points in common? *Zero!* Neat and tidy, whereas the other definitions involve a lot of extra work, measuring infinitely-many distances or at least a couple of angles. But, doggonit, it's just so *convenient* in algebraic geometry to say "lines with the same slope are parallel", or in linear algebra to say "vectors with the same (or proportional) components are parallel". [My favorite trigonometric diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle#Trigonometric_functions_on_the_unit_circle) has a nifty mnemonic that "reciprocal functions appear as parallel segments": $\sin \parallel \csc$ and $\cos \parallel \sec$; the "same direction" interpretation allows me to include $\tan \parallel \cot$ (and also $1 \parallel 1$), and it keeps the mnemonic from breaking down on a technicality at $0^\circ$ and $90^\circ$ when pairs of these "parallel" segments *coincide*. In the latter cases, being a stickler about "zero points in common" can get in the way of what's *important* about the situation.

The point is: One can make the case that coincident lines *are* parallel, and one can make the case the they *aren't*. Every day, mathematicians use the word "parallel" in ways that favor one choice over the other, and they freely change their minds depending on context. What they *don't* do, however, is leave their audience guessing on the matter, the way Humpty does to Alice. If there's potential confusion over any definition, a good mathematician gives explicit clarification about "what I choose [the word] to mean".

A common way of barring coincident lines from the Parallel Club is to be very vigilant to use the word "distinct" to describe the lines in question; that's why you see so many answers here making a big deal about the word. Another strategy is perhaps to use phrasing such a "strictly parallel" ... the latter being akin to describing a company's profit as "strictly positive", because somewhere someone might be asking this version of your question:

> Can "profit" be zero?

Comment: I think it is an interesting question what "constant distance" between two lines actually means - it requires some definition of distance, which may not be a primitive concept, while incidence tends to be primitive (properties defined in axioms).

Comment: I'm probably just being annoying, but for the lack of any formal definition of what it is for two curves to 'meet', we would have to resort to what the word means in common English. But then, the word has connotations of describing two objects coming together when they previously *weren't* together (I 'meet' my old friend when I see him on a bus after a long time, but my two lungs never 'met', since they were created together and never have been apart.) This would mean it's either all in favour or 3-to-1 for 'coincident lines are parallel'.

Comment: Don't get me wrong; I understand your answer and how it's terminology that isn't strictly defined and depends on how the speaker means it, but this seems worthy of consideration too. I suppose until a strict definition by some mathematical union is enacted, all the above is useless, though

Comment: @harry: There's a perfectly good formal definition for what it is for two curves to "meet": *They have a point in common.* That is to say, some point is *incident* to both curves, or the intersection of the curves' sets of points is non-empty, etc. The notion of incidence itself (as Mark Bennet notes) tends to be an axiomatic primitive, so it *is* subject to interpretation —in analytic geometry, the axiom amounts to "A point is incident to a curve when the coordinates of the point satisfy the equation of the curve"— but once established, it brings along the notion of two curves "meeting".

Comment: Thanks for responding; could you show me where you got the definition from? Since there doesn't seem to be a singular authority for definitions for Maths (like the IUPAC for chemistry), I'm not sure where to refer for conclusive terminology.

Comment: @harry: Variation of wording is allowed in the mathematical literature; it is, after all, *literature!* :) Authors are free to use whatever turns-of-phrase suit them, their subject, and their audience. ... There is no "authority", but for *example*, see Wikipedia's ["Hilbert's Axioms" entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_axioms). The first item under "Indicence" describes the notion as "containment", but notes that "we may also employ other forms of expression" ... because *of course* we may. There are typically many ways to convey the same basic notion.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Math terminology had been bothering me for quite a while, thanks a lot!

Comment: A way to have 1. and 2. coexist is to say that two coinciding lines are not two lines at all, but one and the same. Then 1 and 2 simply don't apply and thus don't contradict each other.

Answer (score 2):

The second definition--the equidistant property--is the definition with which most everyone is familiar... Euclid's 5th postulate.

However, in non-Euclidean geometry, parallel lines are not necessarily equidistant at all corresponding points.  So the first definition is a more generalized definition.

In both definitions, parallel lines cannot intersect.  I "assume" this is what was meant by the "side-by-side" reference in the 2nd definition.  Since any line intersects itself at infinitely many points, then no, you cannot have coincident and parallel lines.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the first definition of two **distinct** lines are acceptable in three geometries we know, i.e; *Euclidean*, *Spherical* and *Hyperbolic*. I made the word *distinct* bold cause if two lines are not such that, so why are we working on them? If they are *coincides*, so does it have any senses we speak about **two** lines (They are one line and we don't want this case). So, we always assume that two lines are **distinct** and so speaking about **zero distance** doesn't make any senses. In Geometry, what you noted inside **Edit** shouldn't happen. Unless, in that case we are nothing to do with two lines.

Moreover about the second point you noted: I wanted to tell you this is true in Euclidean Geometry. This definition is absolutely **wrong** in other two geometries. In Hyperbolic, we have many many lines which are parallel to just one line asymptotically. And in  Spherical one, we don't have any parallel lines!

[image]

Comment: You're an "old hat" at sketches!

Comment: Can you please clarify your answer? I find it a little difficult to understand. Also, if you say that two lines need to be equidistant then what about lines that have a distance of zero between them?

Comment: Surely, we know more than the three geometries you mention, even if you restrict yourself two planar geometries. As for the other point you make, in 3-dimensional Elliptic geometry, it is quite possible to have two lines "side by side and having the same distance continuously between them". They are called Clifford parallels.

Comment: @AndreySokolov: Thanks for noting me that. Honestly, I mention just the Classic ones. If you have an article about Clifford paralles, may I ask to be shared with you?

Answer (score 2):

The second defitinion is incomplete: two lines are parallel if they 1) do not intersect 2) maintain a constant separation between points closest to each other on the two lines. This second definition works for both two and three dimensional Euclidean space.

It is easy to visualize two parallel lines in two dimensions (a plane) as two lines that will never cross if extended infinitely; since they never cross, the first property (no intersection) is fulfilled. You'll also notice that the two lines maintain a constant distance apart.

Three dimensions is a little trickier, but not too bad. We live in three dimensions of space, so just imagine tying string from one wall of your room to another as a line. Obviously there are many ways to tie two different strings across your room that they don't intersect each other. (For example, tie your left/right walls together, and your front/back.) This is where the second property comes into play; two strings (lines) are parallel if when you pick any "starting" point on string $A$ and measure the shortest distance to string $B$ it equals the same distance as if you'd pick any other starting point. Think about why this holds for two dimensions, and you'll realize that the only way to achieve this in three dimensions is for the lines to lay in a plane. (For Euclidean {"standard"} space)

Your first definition only holds for two-dimensional space; it implies that the distance between them is constant, so it means the same as the [completed] second definition.

Comment: Nicely done Alex. (+1)

Comment: Can you please explain the second point a little more? What you mean by "constant separation between points closet to each other on the two lines"?

Comment: @gekkostate, Certainly. I added two paragraphs to my original answer that I hope clears things up. If not, let me know; I'm more than willing to clarify further if need-be.

Comment: @gekkostate, also notice that coincident lines cannot be parallel, since they intersect (everywhere).

Answer (score 2):

Lines are parallel iff they are distinct, non-intersecting, and not diverging.  If you can travel along one of them arbitrarily far, and after some finite distance, any further travel will only make them get further apart, then they are diverging, and if not, they are parallel.

Lines that don't intersect are "non-secant".  All parallel lines are also non-secant, and in 2D Euclidean geometry, all non-secants are parallel, but in 3D or Hyberbolic 2D, non-secant lines can be non-parallel.

A curve distinct from yet equidistant from a line (or something else like a point) is an Equidistant Curve.  In non-euclidean geometry, equidistant curves to lines are never lines themselves.  In 3D euclidean geometry, they may be, but might not be lines.  Only in 2D euclidean geometry are equidistant curves to lines necessarily lines themselves.

Now for the really strange bit.  Remember how parallel is defined in terms of moving along a line.  That means being parallel has a direction.  In Euclidean geometry, parallel lines are always parallel in both directions, but hyperbolic lines are only parallel in one direction, and they diverge in the other direction.  So given a line, and a point not on that line, there are two parallel lines, one in each direction.

The following diagram shows a Poincare Disc model of the Hyperbolic plane. The points around the edge are "ideal points" while those within are real points.  Hyperbolic lines map to circular arcs perpendicular to the edge of the disc.

[image: Poincare Disc Model of the Hyperbolic Plane]

It hows Line $\overline{AB}$ and real point $C$.  Perpendicular to $\overline{AB}$ through $C$ is $\overline{EF}$, and perpendicular to that through $C$ is $\overline{HG}$ which is nonsecant to $\overline{AB}$, but not parallel to it, note how they diverge to infinity in both directions.  $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{AK}$ are parallel, but only in the direction of ideal point $A$, they diverge toward $B$.  Similarly, $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{BJ}$ are parallel toward $B$. The dashed arc $\overset{\displaystyle\frown} {BCA}$ is actually an equidistant curve, not a line, note how it meets the edge of the dist at a non-right angle.