# How do you find which planes are parallel?

Tags: linear-algebra

im really confuse how to figure this one out... Can someone please help me

[image]

Comment: Two planes are parallel if (and only if) they don't meet, so if (and only if) the two equations have no common solution. So, you know how to find solutions of two linear equations in three unknowns?

Comment: A plane with equation $ax+by+cz=d$ has normal vector $(a,b,c)$. Two planes are parallel if their normal vectors are proportional. With these indications, work this issue **by yourself** !

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Planes can meet and be parallel (i.e. coincident planes:  they are scalar multiples of each other).

Comment: @Andrew I wouldn't call planes (or lines) parallel, if they are coincident. Do you have a cite for this definition?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Did some digging and found [a discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/411249/what-is-a-parallel-line).  I choose to accept that coincident lines are parallel lines that maintain a distance of zero from each other (but I'm not sure I want to get into the argument of what "distance" is lol)

Answer (score 1):

Hints: Let ${\bf n_i}$ be the normal of plane $i=1,2,3,4$. Notice that

\begin{align*}
{\bf n_1} &= (15, -6, 24) \\
{\bf n_2} &= (-5,2,-8) \\
{\bf n_3} &= (6,-4,4) \\
{\bf n_4} &= (3,-2,-2) \\
\end{align*}

What happens when the normals of two planes are parallel?